# How to show vertical or horizontal scroller on UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiweb

I ma using UIWebView to some html content. And some time the data is more in width or height but I have fixed size UIWebView. So for user perspective I want to show scroller vertical or horizontal to indicate the user that there are some more content are available in this view. I am using 
[webView.scrollView flashScrollIndicators];
but it show scroller when I touch UIWebView. I want to show scroller by default. Can you suggest how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Use the scroll view of the webviw like this:

```
   [(YOUR WEBVIEW).scrollView  setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
   [(YOUR WEBVIEW)scrollView  setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
```

You can do one thing that ,use this

```
   - (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView){

        [(YOUR WEBVIEW).scrollView flashScrollIndicators];

     }
```

It Will show the scroll-indicator when downloading of the content will finish and user will easily understand that , there are more content on the bottom of the page.

Comment: I have already used it but this work after user interaction with UIWebview. Defaulty it not works.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is simple - **you can't** as it is against the human interface guidelines. There is a reason that the only way you can manually get them to show is by calling `flashScrollIndicators`. Apple didn't intend for you to show them so if you're going to implement this, it's going to be the hard way (subclassing or creating your own UIWebView).

> Appearance and Behavior
>
> When a scroll view first appears—or when users interact with it—vertical or horizontal scroll indicators **flash briefly** to show users that there is more content they can reveal. Other than the transient scroll indicators, a scroll view has no predefined appearance.
>
> A scroll view responds to the speed and direction of gestures to reveal content in a way that feels natural to people. When users drag content in a scroll view, the content follows the touch; when users flick content, the scroll view reveals the content quickly and stops scrolling when the user touches the screen or when the end of the content is reached. A scroll view can also operate in paging mode, in which each drag or flick gesture reveals one app-defined page of content.

[Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html) - iOS UI Element Usage Guidelines